# For loop if statement stopping on first case

Tags: javascript

The challenge:

> Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed (Just like the name of this Kata). Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.
>
> Example:
>
> `spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" )` => returns `"Hey wollef sroirraw"`

At the moment I have this

```
function spinWords(str) {
  var splitArray = str.split(' ')
  for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i].length > 5) {
      var long = splitArray[i].split('').reverse('').join('')
      return long
      i++
    } else {
      var short = splitArray[i]
      return short
      i++
    }
  }
}
```

This is working properly but will only return the first element in the array as reversed or not. Why is the loop not looping?

Comment: `return` terminates the function

Comment: I did not know that, where should I put the return statement?

Comment: No code is run after a `return` statement.

Comment: Put it at the end of the function. And you need to concatenate the result of each iteration into a string to return at the end.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp Just saw your other comment. It depends on what result you want. If you think about it, what were you planning to do with the data you were returning? How did you expect 2 return statements to be read from? How did you plan to recover the data, and how did you plan to use it? Your answer lies in that question.

Comment: Also consider using the `map()` method. You can then return the appropriate value for each word, and combine the results after mapping.

Comment: You don't need `i++` in the `if` statements, you're already doing that in the `for` header. If you do that, you skip every other element of the array.

Comment: You can simply do `splitArray[i] = <code that reverses it>`. Then at the end do `return splitArray.join(' ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there..

1. using for loop, you do not want to do another i++..
2. you said that it would be 5 or more.. so it should be >=5
3. return terminates the for loop, so use it last..

the modified function can look like this:

```
function spinWords(str){
 var splitArray = str.split(' ');
 var spinnedWords = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i].length >= 5) {
      var long = splitArray[i].split('').reverse('').join('');
      spinnedWords = spinnedWords.concat(' ' + long);
    }
    else {
     var short = splitArray[i]
     spinnedWords = spinnedWords.concat(' ' + short);
    }
  }
  return spinnedWords.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return ends the function.
Another approach.

```js
const spinWords = words =>
  words
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => (word.length >= 5 ? [...word].reverse().join("") : word))
    .join(" ");

console.log(spinWords("Hey fellow warriors"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things must be changed for this code to work properly.

**First**
The `return` statement will finish the entire function execution. So it should be placed at the end of the body when no more code will be executed.

**Second**
You can switch the values you are iterating over and then return the same array with the inverted operation of the first line (`.join(' ')`).

**Third**
The `for` loop already increment the index counter at the end of each iteration if you defined it in the parameters. You don't need `i++` inside the loop body.

```js
function spinWords(str) {
  var splitArray = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i].length >= 5) {
      var long = splitArray[i]
        .split('')
        .reverse('')
        .join('');
      splitArray[i] = long;
    }
  }
  return splitArray.join(' ')
}
```

*EDIT: There's no need for `else` statement*

*EDIT2: I forgot the third change needed*

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer after your tips:

```
function spinWords(str){
 var splitArray = str.split(' ') 
 var finalArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
  if (splitArray[i].length >= 5) {
    var long = splitArray[i].split('').reverse('').join('')
  finalArray.push(long)
    
  }
    else {
     var short = splitArray[i]
     finalArray.push(short)
    }
    
    
}
  return finalArray.join(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function spinWords(str) {
  return str
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => word.length >= 5 ? word.split("").reverse().join("") : word)
    .join(" ");
}

console.log( spinWords("Hey fellow warriors") );
```